# XmlTextWriter path error?

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is wrong with the following statement?

```
XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(@"D:\project\data\" + System.DateTime.Today + @"\" + System.DateTime.Now + ".xml", null);
```

When I try the above statement it gives the following error

> The given path's format is not supported.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Illegal characters aside, what you're trying to do is impossible for one simple reason: as long as `XmlTextWriter` *will* create file if it doesn't exist, it **won't create directory**. And that's what you're trying to do:

```
XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(
    /* your root path */ @"D:\project\data\" +
    /* NEW directory  */ System.DateTime.Today + @"\" +
    /* new file name  */ System.DateTime.Now + ".xml", null);
```

You either need to create directories for given day manually:

```
var path = string.Format(@"D:\project\data\{0:yyyyMMdd}", DateTime.Now);
// if directory already exists nothing will happen
Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

Or merge date into file name:

```
var fileName = string.Format(@"D:\project\data\{0:yyyyMMdd}_{0:HHmmssfff}.xml",
    DateTime.Now);
```

Answer (score 2):

File names can't contain various symbols, `:` is one of the illegal characters.  Try using something like this instead:

```
String.Format(@"D:\project\data\{0:yyyyMMdd}\{0:HHmmssfff}.xml", DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: but when I try to use `doc.Load(@"D:\project\data.xml");` it doesn't give any error, while `doc` is an `XmlDocument` datatype.

Comment: Heh, sorry, I should have been a bit more specific.  The colon is only permitted in a file path immediately after a drive letter, not in folder or file names.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your language settings (locale), the date or time format may contain illegal characters for a file name. For example, German time format contains a colon ':', and English date formats contain '/', both of which are not allowed in file or directory names.

Find out which illegal characters are generated by your locale, and either use an explicit format in [DateTime.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), or remove them by applying ToString().Replace(":", "") etc.

Comment: then how do I do it? my system locale is set to US

Comment: now when I converted the date and time to string it gives this error `Could not find a part of the path 'D:\project\data\14022012\161428.xml'.`